# Rspec: test not passing when it should

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

The second test here passes fine, the first doesn't. No idea why.

```
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe UserNotesController do

  context 'GET #index' do

    let(:note) { build(:user_note) }

    specify 'populates an array of notes' do
      expect(:user_notes).to eq [note]
    end

    specify 'renders the :index view' do
      get :index
      expect(response).to render_template :index
    end
  end
end
```

Not sure why it's not passing but I'm getting this message.

```
(compared using ==)

Diff:
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
-[#<UserNote id: nil, user_id: 2, creator_id: nil, note: "Magnam quas fugit nihil.", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, follow_up: nil>]
+:user_notes
```

I'm pretty new to Rspec. Any help?

Comment: You didn't describe what do you use for emulating database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access an instance variable `@foo` in an rspect test you reference it with `assigns(:foo)`

```
expect(assigns(:user_notes)).to eq [note]
```

You're also missing the call to the action.  It should be...

```
get :index
expect(assigns(:user_notes)).to eq [note]
```

Lastly, the `let(:note) { build(:user_note) }` is lazy and doesn't execute until the variable is referenced... which is only AFTER the get :index, and build won't save to the database in any case, so change it to ...

```
let!(:note) { create(:user_note) }
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, still get the error though: `expected: [#<UserNote id: nil, user_id: 3, creator_id: nil, note: "Minima enim molestias dicta velit quo assumenda ea ...", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, follow_up: nil>]` and `got: nil`.

Comment: Ah... you also need to do `get :index` before the expect  :)

Comment: @SteveTurczyn add that to the answer, as that's the first problem with the spec

Comment: Same problem, except it's now `got: []` and not `nil`. Am I missing something totally stupid?

Comment: Perhaps change to `let(:note) { create(:user_note) }`

Comment: The `[]` is a good sign. :)  But the record isn't being created until the note variable is explicitly referenced in the test.  Modified my answer to suggest you use 'let!` instead of `let`

Comment: As @zishe pointed out, create will write to the database, build will build the record but won't save it, so it's not in the database for the index action to retrieve.